# const 変数でアクセスエラーが出る理由 const_cast<>()

Tags: c++

const_castの使い方なのですがなぜ`const int z = 0`をソースファイルの一番外側に書くとアクセスエラーにり`int main()`の中(//コメント部)に書くとエラーが起きないのでしょうか？
`const int z = 0`をソースファイルの一番外側に書いた場合をどうすればアクセスエラーを防げるのかを教えてほしいです。

```
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include "math.h"
#include <list>
using namespace std;

const int z = 0;

int main() {

    //const int z = 0;

    int *zz = const_cast<int*>(&z);
    *zz = 5;
    cout << *zz;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: アセンブラコードを見ると分かるかと思いますが、グローバルスコープ(static storage)で初期値が設定されている const 変数は .rodata セクションに配置され、ローカル変数(automatic storage)の場合はスタックに置かれるためです([constant initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) の Notes を参照)。ただし、コンパイラの最適化によって消えて無くなる可能性があります。例えば g++ version 7.3.0 でオプション `-O` を付けてコンパイルすると、上記のコードはエラーにはなりません。

Comment: visual studio 2018なのですが、グローバルスコープの場合はそもそもできないということでよろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: できなくはないのですが(例えば `const volatile int z = 0;` に変更、ただし VS2018 でどうなるかは不明)、意味がないのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[複数あるキャスト記法をどのように使い分ければいいか教えてください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/44260)
でも書きましたが
[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) 言語仕様書 ISO/IEC 14882:1998 (古くてごめん) によると
5.2.11 const cast の 7 を引用
定値性キャストを使って定値修飾子を落としてしまって得たデータメンバのポインタ、左辺値、またはポインタを介して書き込みを行うと未定義の動作を生じるかもしれない。

つまり `const` なオブジェクト（変数と言い換えてもOK) 提示例では `z` を、 `const_cast` でその `const` 性質を無理やりはがして書き込みアクセスするのは未定義動作です。未定義動作とは
[C : 配列の添字について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/15206/)
で解説してありますが、要するにバグっているプログラムであって何の動作保証もないってことです。
- 実行時エラーが検出されることもある
- プログラマの勝手な期待通りに動く場合もある
ってあたりが厄介ですね。

なので質問「エラーを防げますか」に対する答えは「ありません」（そのようなプログラムはバグっているので、そういう書き方はダメ）ということになります。

実際、組み込み系ワンチップマイコンではコンパイル時に値が確定している  `const` なオブジェクトは変更されないことを前提に ROM 上に配置され、貴重な RAM を使わずに済むようになりますが、当然、実行時に変更することは不可能です。

Answer (score 0):

できるできないという話以前に、そもそもconst変数の値を変更するようなコードを書くべきではない（もしくはconstにする意味が無い）、と思うのですが。

それとも意外とそういう用途（ハック？）があるのでしょうか？
もしあるなら、後学のために教えて欲しいです。

Comment: 初期化処理の時に値を設定してそれいこう変更できないようにしたいのですが実装に困り質問を作成しました。

Comment: なるほど、ならむしろその内容で質問を立てた方が、他の人にも有意義だったように思います。
値は実行時に与えたいということでしょうか。
（#defineでコンパイル時にオプション指示するのではダメなんでしょうね）

クラスメンバ変数であれば、constでもコンストラクタの初期化子で初期化できるので、コンストラクタの引数として与える方法があるとは思いますが。
他に方法があるのであれば、私も知りたいです。(^^;)